# Is it safe and fine to block external access to sites/all/modules folder and all its subfolders and files?

Tags: security

That's to say block all except 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Define "safe". Also, a lot depends on what modules exactly you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about blocking HTTP access (for browsers), then it won't give you any additional security.

But if you nevertheless want to do so, then exclude `*.css`, `*.js` and all images from being blocked.